# how can I achieve text color of rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54) tailwind css?

Tags: tailwind-css

how can I achieve text color of rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54) tailwind css.
I have tried text-black-500, text-current and many other variations but couldn't achieve color of rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Tailwind allows you to control color opacity using classes.

Example: `text-black/50` (equivalent to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)`)

In Tailwind v3, there are a couple of ways to set a text color value of `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)`:

### 1. Use an arbitrary value

For one-off values, it doesn't always make sense to define them in your theme config file. In those cases, it can be quicker and easier to pass in an arbitrary value instead.

Example: `text-black/[.54]`

### 2. Define a custom opacity scale value of 54

In your `tailwind.config.js file`, register a new opacity value.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      opacity: {
        '54': '.54',
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Usage: `text-black/54`

When taking this option, you may wish to give the value a more descriptive name.

Comment: If you want to use rgba in arbitrary, you can write `text-[rgba(0,0,0,0.54)]`. Pay attention to spaces between rgba arguments, remove them, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 14):

You need to define a custom color class on `tailwind.config.js`

```
 module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'black-rgba': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)',
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="text-black-rgba text-4xl">Hi there!</span>
```

[Working example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/FoDvWc3tdZ)

Answer (score 9):

Another way of doing this with Tailwind 2 is to use the classes: `text-black text-opacity-50` or `bg-black bg-opacity-50`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using tailwindcss version 2 or more, you can use **Just-in-Time Mode**. Please take a look at this [link](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode). For specific text color you have to put color in square bracket. Like this one `text-[rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)]`. It is far more easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

or use an online rgba to hex converter like - [rgbacolorpicker](https://rgbacolorpicker.com/rgba-to-hex) and use the code like this - className="bg-[#0000008a]"